# Communication between 2 process many times with message queue in C

Tags: pipe, fork, ipc

I have some problem in IPC (Inter Process Communication). The task is making 2 program: P1 & P2. P1 create a child, P1-parent takes integer from  console, send to P1-child through PIPE. P1-child receives integer and send it to P2 through Message Queue and wait for reply.Then, P1 comes back in step take integer from console, and so on. P2 receives value from P1 and reply with OK. Afterthat, P2 waits for message from P1.
I did the task one time, but I can't make it done in the next time. If I add While(1) loop, P1 loop infinite in the second time. How I can make it done many times. I think the problem is the order of child and parent excute the code in P1. But I can't fix it.
Here is P1 code:

```
if (pid > 0)
    {
  /*
   * 1.Accept input from console
   */

  printf("Input a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &numb);
  sprintf(str, "%d", numb);

  /*
   * 2.Send input to child with pipe
   */

  close(pipe_p2c[0]);
  write(pipe_p2c[1], str, strlen(str) + 1);
  close(pipe_p2c[1]);
}
  if (pid == 0)
{
  /*
   * 3.Child receive input
   */

  close(pipe_p2c[1]);
  read(pipe_p2c[0], str_recv, MAXSZ);
  close(pipe_p2c[0]);

  /*
   * 4.Send received value to P2 by msq
   */

  sbuf.mtype = 1;
  strcpy(sbuf.mtext, str_recv);
  printf("%s\n", sbuf.mtext);
  buf_length = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1;

  if((msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buf_length, 0)) < 0)
    {
      perror("msgsend");
      exit(1);
    }

  /*
   * 5.Receive reply
   */

  if((msgrcv(msqid, &rbuf, MSGSZ, 1, 0)) < 0)
    {
      perror("msgrcv");
      exit(1);
    }

  printf("Received message : %s\n", rbuf.mtext);

} // end if - else (pid ==0)
```

Here is P2 code:

```
if ((msgrcv(msqid, &rbuf, MSGSZ, 1, 0)) < 0) 
  {
    perror("msgrcv");
    exit(1);
  }

printf("Received message = %s\n", rbuf.mtext);
sscanf(rbuf.mtext, "%d", &numb);

sprintf(sbuf.mtext, "%s", "OK");
sbuf.mtype = 1;
buf_length = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1;

if ((msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buf_length, 0)) < 0) 
  {
    perror("msgsend");
    exit(1);
  }
```